# Unable to run first appium test

Tags: selenium, appium

I am trying to run basic appium test that launch apk into device. but i am getting errors. And i am confused how to run appium test into Android studio.[enter image description here][1]

Environment

```
Appium version (or git revision) that exhibits the issue:Appium v1.4.16
Last Appium version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable):NA
Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: Windows 10 64 bit
Node.js version (unless using Appium.app|exe):v4.4.7
Mobile platform/version under test: Android 5.1
Real device or emulator/simulator: Real Device
Appium CLI or Appium.app|exe: Appium.exe
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiGSK.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwLLx.jpg)

> [TestNG] Running:
>   C:\Users\prabu\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1847523077\testng-customsuite.xml
>
> [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\Default suite\Default
>   test.xml [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\Default suite exists:
>   true FAILED: start
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: 'unknown',
>   revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700' System info:
>   host: 'Vaibhav-PC', ip: '192.168.0.114', os.name: 'Windows 10',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver
>   info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:670)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
>     at demo.StartAppium.start(StartAppium.java:36)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57) Caused
>   by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:649)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native
>   Method)   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
>     ... 42 more
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>
> ## =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@1b0375b3: 38 ms
>   [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\testng-failed.xml
>   [Utils]   Directory C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\Default
>   suite\testng-failed.xml [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\Default suite exists:
>   true [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0
>   skipped=0]: 21 ms [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@48140564: 13 ms [Utils] Attempting to
>   create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\junitreports\TEST-demo.StartAppium.xml
>   [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\junitreports exists:
>   true [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@3b6eb2ec: 12 ms [Utils]
>   Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\toc.html [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default suite
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\Default test.properties [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default suite
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\index.html [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default suite
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\main.html [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default suite
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\groups.html [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default suite
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\classes.html [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default suite
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\reporter-output.html [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default suite
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\methods-not-run.html [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default suite
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default
>   suite\testng.xml.html [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\Default suite
>   exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create
>   C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old\index.html [Utils]
>   Directory C:\AndroidDemoworkspace\StartAppium\test-output\old exists:
>   true [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1134affc: 49 ms [TestNG] Time
>   taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@3ac3fd8b: 7 ms

Comment: Share DesiredCapibilities you specified in your code

Comment: since the connection refused error is comming  , so i believe there might be problems with the desired capabilities

Comment: Appium working fine now... Actually i have made few mistakes like adding wrong jar files, environment variables wrong.. Thanks everyone to reply me. But i want to explore it more . suggest me demo examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not added selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar and java-client-3.2.0.jar files properly. Now test cases executes correctly.